# How can we retain ngx-datepicker values in angular 8

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

How can we retain the value of ngx-bootstrap date picker, on ngModel change,

```
<input type="text"
       placeholder="Daterangepicker"
       [value]="date"
       class="form-control"
      bsDaterangepicker>
```

in my ts

```
date = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I could not get a clear idea from the `ts` you provided but this is an example that you may benefit from:

**The HTML :**

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       bsDatepicker [bsValue]="bsValue" 
       [(ngModel)]="student.dateOfBirth" 
/>
```

**The ts:**

```
show(studentId?: number): void {
        this._studentService.getStudentFor(studentId).subscribe(studentResult => {
            this.bsValue = moment(this.student.dateOfBirth, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate();
            this.active = true;
            this.modal.show();
        });
    }
```

Comment: why do you use bsvalue and ngmodel both?